# Haskell type classes hierarchy

Tags: haskell, type-families

I have 2 classes:

```
class (IsColor (ColorType a)) => ColorList a where
    type ColorType a :: *
    foreground :: a -> (ColorType a)
    background :: a -> (ColorType a)

class (ColorList (ThemeColorList a)) => Theme a where
    type ThemeColorList a :: *
    renderTheme :: a -> b
```

I have function dosomething with type signature:

```
 dosomething :: (IsColor a) => a -> Int
```

I define instance of Theme class for data type SimpleTheme:

```
data SimpleTheme a = SimpleTheme a

instance (ColorList a) => Theme (SimpleTheme a) where
    type ThemeColorList (SimpleTheme a) = a
    renderTheme theme = dosomething $ background theme
```

If in renderTheme I do something with background or foreground, I get compilation error:

```
Could not deduce (IsColor (ColorType (SimpleTheme a)))
      arising from a use of ‘dosomething’
    from the context (ColorList (ThemeColorList (SimpleTheme a)),
                      ColorList a)
      bound by the instance declaration at
```

How to solve problem?

Comment: the type of `renderTheme` seems too general (for all `b`, really?)

Comment: No, I wrote b, because it does not matter. Let type of b is Int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix that single problem by changing the definition of `renderTheme` in the `SimpleTheme` instance. The context only requires that there be a `ColorList a` instance, not a `ColorList (SimpleTheme a)`, so we can use `background` on the `a` held in a `SimpleTheme`, but can't use `background` on the whole `SimpleTheme`.

```
    renderTheme (SimpleTheme a) = dosomething $ background a
```

#### Explanation of the error

From the context

```
(ColorList (ThemeColorList (SimpleTheme a)),
 ColorList a)
```

We can deduce the following.

- Since there's a `ColorList a` there must be what is required for a `ColorList`. That is, there's a type `ColorType a` and an instance `IsColor (ColorType a)`.
- Since there's a `ColorList (ThemeColorList (SimpleTheme a))`  there must be what is required for a `ColorList`. that is, there's a type `ColorType (ThemeColorList (SimpleTheme a))` and an instance `IsColor (ThemeColorList (SimpleTheme a))`.

None of these is an instance for `IsColor (ColorType (SimpleTheme a))`, which is why you get the error.